# How to get datewise total in table using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

i want to get the data in my table date wise with total
Here is my code what am trying to do

```
var result = from a in db.table
                      group a by a.date.Date into g
                      select new { date = g.Key, distance = g.Sum(a => a.distance) };
 return View(result.ToList());
```

If am using without Date part then am getting every data in a day.
But by using this linq am getting error "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties".

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as Date is class and is not supported by entity framework. you need to use truncate time function which converts datetime to date.

```
var result = from a in db.table
                      group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.date) into g
                      select new { date = g.Key, distance = g.Sum(a => a.distance) };
 return View(result.ToList());
```

[Entity Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(v=vs.110).aspx)